# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I want to create a function that receives a JSON object and map it to the right class structure. 
I am using Postman to send the JSON object 
[rest API](http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strongbad/objectKey)
   { "id" :1 }

I have been looking for a solution to fix the upper exception but none of the suggested answers solve my problem.
By the way I imported " **EclipseLink** " library and that did not help.

Postman error message :

```
 {
  "timestamp": 1466965904019,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javax.xml.bind.JAXBException",
  "message": "property \"eclipselink.media-type\" is not supported",
  "path": "/api/v1/strongbad/objectKey"
}
```

```java
package com.books.controller;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/")
public class StrongBadController{

    @RequestMapping(value="strongbad/objectKey",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public String unMarshallObject(@RequestBody String jsonObject) throws JAXBException{

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {StrongBad.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader json =new StringReader(jsonObject);
        StrongBad strongBad2 = (StrongBad) unmarshaller.unmarshal(json);

        return "";
    }

    class StrongBad implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         private String id;

        public StrongBad() {
            super();
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


    }
}
```

```java
2016-06-26 13:31:43.986 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /api/v1/strongbad/objectKey
2016-06-26 13:31:43.987 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.books.controller.StrongBadController.unMarshallObject(java.lang.String) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException]
2016-06-26 13:31:44.003 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read [class java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@6ff6d3a7]
2016-06-26 13:31:44.008 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.books.controller.StrongBadController.unMarshallObject(java.lang.String) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException]: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported
2016-06-26 13:31:44.009 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.books.controller.StrongBadController.unMarshallObject(java.lang.String) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException]: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported
2016-06-26 13:31:44.009 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.books.controller.StrongBadController.unMarshallObject(java.lang.String) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException]: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported
2016-06-26 13:31:44.012 DEBUG 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:115) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.books.controller.StrongBadController.unMarshallObject(StrongBadController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]

2016-06-26 13:31:44.014 ERROR 84300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported] with root cause

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:115) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.books.controller.StrongBadController.unMarshallObject(StrongBadController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: What version of eclipselink are you using?

Comment: I am using V 2.5.2

Answer (score 3):

To serialize a POJO into JSON using JAXB you will have to use a custom JAXB runtime like e.g. EclipseLink MOXy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

According to the discovery process, you will have to put a jaxb.properties file in the same package as your model classes (e.g. src/main/resources/com/books/controller) with the following content:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

See also: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jaxb_json_pojo_serialization_example

If that doesn't work try to do this before:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.context.factory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by creating a POJO class in a different file, removing consumes="application/json" and BOOM :)

PS: I tested my API using POSTMAN tool.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/saif_api", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSomething(@RequestBody List<Saif> saifList) {

        //Write a code here
        return "Object Id: " + strongbadList.get(0).getId();
    }


public class Saif {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```